# Access configuration resources in Scala IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide, typesafe-stack

Some of my colleagues use Eclipse 3.7.2 and Scala IDE 2.1 for development.  I want to use [typesafe's config module](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) for applicaton configuration.  I want to use the convention based default configuration location.  According to the examples and documentation, the default config can be found at the following path relative to project root

```
/src/main/resources/application.conf
```

But when I run my project using Scala IDE's Scala Application loader, the SimpleConfig type is unable to load any configuration values set in this file.  An alternative is to pass in a config-file system property via sbt, but I don't want to have to explicitly set this path somewhere.  Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.foo.dataservices.MyServer.main(MyServer.scala)
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'bar'
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:115)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:138)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:150)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:155)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfigNumber(SimpleConfig.java:170)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getInt(SimpleConfig.java:181)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add your resources folder to your java build path:

1. Right Click on your project in the Project Explorer
2. properties -> click Java Build Path -> select "Source" tab
3. click "Add Folder..." and add your src/main/resources folder

update:  if you are using the sbt eclipse plugin you can configure it to automatically add the resources folder to the classpath :

(from: [sbteclipse docs](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/wiki/Using-sbteclipse))

`EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.Default + EclipseCreateSrc.Resource`

Comment: That did the trick.  Thank you kindly.  I'll look into sbteclipse.

Comment: Put the settings in ~/.sbt/0.13/build.sbt to set for all SBT projects.